# Q: arithmetic and logic instructions x86

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I'm new in assembly language x86 . I did learn the basics of assembly language but still having some problems with arithmetic and logic instructions, as this question, I use MASM assembler

```
Q) Given a 64-bit word stored at address N1
a- Declare the variable
b- Increment the value of N1
c- Negate the value of N1
```

The first thing I though about it is how to declare the variable N1?
is it like this ?or I did it in a wrong way?

> N1 DW 4 Dup ?

I will be thankful if someone help me with this question.

Comment: That depends on your assembler, but  that could work even if it's a little strange. Normally you'd use the directive for initializing a single 64 bit quantity, which is usually `DQ` (`Q` for quadword). Also, since you will do operations on it, you should give it some initial value and not use `?` which is undefined.

Comment: @Jester I use 86 assembler ,it must be DW 16 bit.

Comment: What is "86 assembler"? Is the name of the program that you assemble your code with "86"?

Comment: @Michael sorry I meant to use to 8086 system.

Comment: We need to know the actual assembler, since the directives depend on that. Just because you are in a 16 bit environment doesn't mean you can't initialize a 64 bit data. Anyway, you can keep using your 4 words if that makes you happier.

Comment: @Jester I use MASM

Comment: See, [MASM has a DQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4s2e44h3.aspx) directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q) Given a 64-bit word stored at address N1

The address could be set with `EQU` like this

```
N1 equ 00007c00h
```

> a- Declare the variable

First, set the offset of the variable with the `ORG` directive and then declare it with `DQ` which means QuadWord(64bit).

```
.data
  org N1
  var1 DQ 0
```

> b- Increment the value of N1

In the `.code` section use

```
inc var1
```

> c- Negate the value of N1

After that, still in the `.code` section, use

```
neg var1
```

That's it.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful.